# Zend php.ini throws error on command line

Tags: command-line, zend-server, php-ini

I try to run a zend framework script on the command line.
This works well but every time I execute a php script it gives me
a lot of warnings and errors back, What is the problem? and how can I resolve this?

I put the zend php.ini in /etc/ because this dir is used default by my command line, when I try to use 'php -c /usr/local/zend/etc/ script.php' It gaves me the same errors.

errors from command line;

```
leny-pc:scripts nickyklaasse$ php -i | grep php.ini
    Failed loading /usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bcmath.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bcmath.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bcmath.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/calendar.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/calendar.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/calendar.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/curl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/curl.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/curl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/exif.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/exif.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/exif.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ftp.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ftp.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ftp.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gettext.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gettext.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gettext.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/posix.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/posix.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/posix.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/soap.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/soap.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/soap.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sqlite.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sqlite.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sqlite.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tokenizer.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tokenizer.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tokenizer.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xmlreader.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xmlreader.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xmlreader.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xsl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xsl.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xsl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/zip.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/zip.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/zip.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imap.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imap.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/imap.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ldap.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ldap.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ldap.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysql.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysqli.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysqli.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mysqli.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tidy.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tidy.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/tidy.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/pgsql.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/pgsql.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/pgsql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gd.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gd.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/gd.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mcrypt.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ctype.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ctype.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/ctype.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sockets.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sockets.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/sockets.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bz2.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bz2.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/bz2.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mbstring.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mbstring.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/mbstring.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/intl.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/intl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/fileinfo.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/fileinfo.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/fileinfo.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/phar.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/phar.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/phar.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /private/etc/php.ini
```

Thanks in advice,

Nicky

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use mac os x!?
When using php on command line this is the location where php is called from: `/usr/bin`. To make sure you use the php version that comes with zend server you have to replace the native php that is located in `/usr/bin`.

**First backup your native php files:**

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.bak
sudo mv /usr/bin/php-cli /usr/bin/php-cli.bak
sudo mv /usr/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config.bak
sudo mv /usr/bin/phpize /usr/bin/phpize.bak
```

Either you copy the above files from `/usr/local/zend/bin` to `/usr/bin` OR **you create a symbolic link to this files (prefered method!)**:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/zend/bin/php-config ./php-config` and so on ...

At the end `/usr/bin` should look similar to this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        23  6 Feb 17:40 php -> /usr/local/zend/bin/php
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        27 25 Dez 23:43 php-cli -> /usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        23 25 Dez 23:43 php-cli.bak
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        30  6 Feb 17:42 php-config -> /usr/local/zend/bin/php-config
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel      3776  6 Feb 15:09 php-config.bak
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel  21488656  6 Feb 15:09 php.bak
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        26 25 Dez 23:44 phpize -> /usr/local/zend/bin/phpize
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        26 25 Dez 23:44 phpize.bak
```